# Hive Odbc "Error from Hive: ETIMEDOUT"

Tags: jdbc, odbc, hive

Getting error while connecting to hiveserver2
Hive server 2 & hadoop is up and running in my local machine

Trying the below code

```
try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc://dsn=hello;driver=Microsoft Hive ODBC Driver;Host=127.0.0.1;Port=5000;HiveServerType=2;AuthMech=0");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SHOW TABLES");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmdData = res.getMetaData();
        int count = rsmdData.getColumnCount();
        while (res.next()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                System.out.print(res.getString(i) + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

I am getting the below error

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][HiveODBC] (34) Error from Hive: ETIMEDOUT.
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Unknown Source)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at hivedev.HiveODBC.main(HiveODBC.java:20)
```

However I am able to connect through beeline cli

Comment: Any specific reason you are using Microsoft's ODBC driver and not the Hive JDBC driver (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-JDBC)? Should not be the source of your problem though. Is the port correct? I think by default it is 10000.

Comment: I got it working by changing the AuthMech to 2